# How to undo system("pause")

Tags: c++

I'm making a program in C++ and did some experimenting. I included the `system('pause')` function. Now obviously I cannot close the program. How do I undo it and quit the program? Do I really need to restart my PC?

Basically I pranked my self. Here is the src code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char answer;

    cout << "Can gh0st be VIP?:(y=Yes/n=No)";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'y')
    {
        cout << "thanx ande =)";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << "time to pay ande ahaha!\a\a\a\a\a\a\a...*with at least 200 more of these*";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "just put the letter y or n lol try it again";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Restart is not enough. You need to buy a new one. (Hint: not really, not really need a new one, not really need to restart)

Comment: Have you tried pressing the enter key? Or did you redirect the input.

Comment: Oh, some code after all... do you realize that there is no `system("pause")` in your code?

Comment: @D.R. sorry, was lost in the copying process

Comment: `system("pause")` will pause the process I think, so there is no way *from the process itself* to unpause. But from the user, simply press a key.

Comment: @Synxis I'm telling you, pressing a key doesn't do anything. Try running the code yourself.

Comment: @TacoCat Just tried it, VS2013, Win8.1 -> works. However, you have to press Enter twice, the first one goes into the cin buffer.

Comment: @TacoCat Works for me (same config as D.R.)

Comment: @TacoCat: I get `sh: 1: pause: not found` and the program exists.

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again?

Answer (score 2):

Press "ENTER".                  .

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: Enter does not help.

Comment: What is the console window's output? Are you even working in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

`pause` is not part of C or C++, this is a command from Windows Command Prompt, which is called using the `system()` syscall.

Once `system()` is called, your thread hangs at that point until whatever program or command you call with `system()` is concluded and returns the exit code.

`pause` is a shell command that will wait for any key to be pressed by the user. Any key pressed will interrupt `pause` and your program will continue.

Just make sure the key you press is NOT the reset button.

Comment: what is wrong with pressing the reset button?

Comment: Nothing, it just won't return control to your program.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `system("pause")` I would encourage doing a

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

This is a longer form of pause that I have found is very easy to use. And also you just hit the little red square close to the help menu.